# R - linear regression through the first point - why is my intuition wrong?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, lm

***Summary :*** **I have fitted my data with a regression line constrained through the first point. This least-squares regression (red line) seems unreliable because of its low slope value.**

Here are my **data** :

```
library(dplyr); library(stats); library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(y = c(3.86, 5.22, 7.77, 8.62, 6.2, 4.39, 3.76, 3.31, 3.26), x = c(0:8))
```

I want to **fit y on x** with a **linear regression through the first point**.

```
intercept <- data$y[1]

lm_model = lm( y-intercept~ x + 0, data = data)
```

I plot the model (regression line in red) :

```
data_1 <- data %>% mutate(y_fitted = lm_model$fitted.values + intercept) 

ggplot(data = data_1, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y), color = "black") + 
  geom_path(aes(y = y_fitted), color = "red")
```

[image]

However, the linear regression seems unreliable **with a too low slope**.

If I multiply the slope by 2.5, I get this new regression that seems more reliable (in orange) :

```
data_1 <- data_1 %>% mutate(y_fitted_bis = lm_model$fitted.values*2.5 + intercept)

ggplot(data = data_1, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y), color = "black") + 
  geom_path(aes(y = y_fitted), color = "red") +
  geom_path(aes(y = y_fitted_bis), color = "orange")
```

[image]

**Why does the red linear regression seem unreliable?**

Comment: Thanks Dario. Unfortunately, that does not answer my question. Using this method provides the same slope value that is likely unreliable.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this question should be "why is my intuition wrong"? rather than "why is my line wrong"? I suspect it has something to do with *leverage* - because you are fixing the first point, small changes to the slope with make large changes in the SSQ associated with the rightmost points in the data set ...

Comment: Ben Bolker, you're right. I have modified my post

Answer (score 2):

Your model is ok (although possibly the first point should be omitted since it is fixed at a 0 residual) but the plotting command has to transform it back to the original coordinates.

```
plot(y ~ x, data)
abline(a = intercept, b = coef(lm_model))
```

Alternately, use a much larger weight for the first point to force it through that point.

```
fm <- lm(y ~ x, data, weights = replace(0*x+1, 1, 10^5))

plot(y ~ x, data)
abline(fm)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Added

Another possibility is to use two lines rather than one.

```
# starting values
fm0.1 <- lm(y ~ x + offset(rep(intercept, length = length(y))) + 0,
  data, subset = seq(4))
fm0.2 <- lm(y ~ x, data, subset = -seq(4))
st <- list(b0 = coef(fm0.1)[[1]], a = coef(fm0.2)[[1]], b = coef(fm0.2)[[2]])

f <- function(x, b0, a, b) pmin(b0 * x + intercept, a + b * x)
fm2 <- nls(y ~ f(x, b0, a, b), data, start = st)

plot(y ~ x, data)
rng <- range(data$x)
with(as.list(coef(fm2)), 
  curve(f(x, b0, a, b), from = rng[1], to = rng[2], add = TRUE))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck. Unfortunately, using your methods returns the same low slope value

Comment: OK. Have revised.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and edits. However, this least squares regression seems unreliable because of its low slope value.

Comment: Maybe it actually *is* low.  You can always try a different model.  Maybe quantreg::rq?

Comment: You may be right

Comment: See Added section for another approach.